# Safari dropdowns cause page refresh / error on click

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, safari

I have no idea how this issue started, but I noticed that in my Rails app **all** `<select>` inputs render differently in Safari and cause a page refresh when you try to click it.

The problem occurs anytime you add styling to the input that changes background, border, or anything that Safari doesn't really like.  A common bootstrap convention adds `class='form-control` to inputs, and this seems to be causing my problem.

This is the input **without** any border:

[image]

This is the same input **with** the addition `style='border: 2px solid red`:

[image]

As you can see the background changes **and** when you click the input, the page refreshes, losing all data in the form, making the form impossible to complete.  I think it might have something to do with webkit?

It's worth noting that the refresh does not hit my server and Safari actually displays this message (with no other detail):
[image]

**If anyone has any idea why this might be happening / how to fix it, please let me know**

Comment: Can you put the code in JSfiddle or pass a URL?

Comment: I've already made an update so it won't work now.  I've tried to make a fiddle and the appearance changes but that error does not occur :/

Comment: This smells like a javascript issue to me. Are you using JS for anything?

Comment: I have a feeling you're right.  When I forced the browser to break on all redirects/errors, the error was part of `core.js` which seemed to be part of webpack